# How do I publish a multi-module Maven build in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a multi-module Maven project that contains a parent POM (which should be published as an artifact) and some jar modules (which should publish `foo-module-1.pom`, `foo-module-1.jar`, and `foo-module-1-sources.jar`). My Azure Pipelines build correctly runs the `package` goal on the project with the `Maven@3` step, but then I get the message that there are no files in the `1/a` directory.

If I simply copy jar files into the Pipelines staging directory, I lose track of the metadata generated in the `target` directories, and POM packages don't have a `target` directory at all. I can use the `deploy` goal, but that bypasses the Release Pipelines and the promotion and similar features.

How do I set up my Azure Pipelines build so that a multi-module Maven repository gets all of its jars and POM artifacts published using the Pipelines management?

Comment: Which task output the `no files` message? Are you using publish build artifacts task? You can try adding two publish build artifacts tasks, and in one task set the `Path to publish` to directories where the jars resides, and in another set the `Path to publish` to the path of .pom file to publish a specific pom file.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT There are 14 POMs, and more will be added. It is not practical to hand-write rules to rename every POM in the way that Maven does automatically.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Have you resolved this issue ?